# Reading the code declarations and definitions in order to get the result of the expression without using GHCi

Tags: haskell

```
data Tree a b = Branch b (Tree a b) (Tree a b) | Leaf a
myorder :: (a -> c) -> (b -> c) -> Tree a b -> [c]
myorder p q (Leaf x) = [p x]
myorder p q (Branch x l r) = myorder p q l ++ [q x] ++ myorder p q r
tree1 = Branch "Hi"
          (Branch "All" (Leaf (1::Int)) (Leaf (2::Int)))
          (Leaf (3::Int))
```

Question asked: What is the result of the following expression?

```
> myorder id length tree1
```

I'm studying for an exam, and I want to get a better understanding of getting the outputs without the GHCi, since of course we have to do it by hand, and I really want to see how do I go by doing it. The answer was [1,3,2,2,3]
If anyone can guide me through it, that would be great.
I also drew out the tree1 like so:

```
     "Hi"
    /   \
 "All"   3
  / \
 1   2
```

Comment: How much of `myorder` *do* you understand?

Comment: You might compare the output to `myorder show id tree1` to get a better feel for how the function works.

Comment: My guess would be is that it order the left side and then the right side and combines them in to a list?

Comment: Also, would I look at myorder :: (a -> c) as (1 -> 3) -> (2 ->3) which does the trasversal and results in [1,3,2,2,3]?

Comment: No, the lowercase letters refer to types, not values. From the type signature, you can roughly describe the behavior of `myorder` as the following: the first argument will be applied to leaves, while the second argument will be applied to interior nodes. The results of both functions will be combined into a single list and returned.

Comment: Oh ok, so Leaf a refers to Int's in tree1 and Branch b refers to the string or char in tree1. Is x in this case the root of the tree? And what is p and q referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to evaluate

```
myorder id length (Branch "Hi"
                    (Branch "All" (Leaf (1::Int)) (Leaf (2::Int)))
                    (Leaf (3::Int)))
```

Try to apply the equations in order from top to bottom.

```
myorder p q (Leaf x) = [p x]
```

This equation does not apply since the argument `Branch "Hi" ... ...` is not of the form `Leaf x`.

```
myorder p q (Branch x l r) = myorder p q l ++ [q x] ++ myorder p q r
```

This equation does apply. We have `p = id`, `q = length`, `x = "Hi"`,

```
l = Branch "All" (Leaf (1::Int)) (Leaf (2::Int)),
r = Leaf (3::Int).
```

So substituting these in the right hand side, the expression becomes

```
   myorder id length (Branch "All" (Leaf (1::Int)) (Leaf (2::Int)))
++ [length "Hi"]
++ myorder id length (Leaf (3::Int)).
```

Now continue.